# How should I name my layouts folder?

Tags: android-layout

I'm building a game for devices running Android API 13 and need to support a number of different devices, including the Note 4, which has display measurements of 480x853dp (https://design.google.com/devices/). So I did the logical thing and put all my layouts into a folder named layout-sw480dp. However, when I start the app, the layouts in the layout folder, rather than layout-sw480dp, get used. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around with the folder name and, for some reason, renaming it to layout-sw320dp did the trick.